General Relativity Book Publication
I am writing a general relativity book for the high school grads and above. I expect my readers to have basics of calculus and vectors and Newtonian Mechanics - I am covering the necessary Special Relativity, Differential Geometry, Tensor Calculus and other basics here. Then I will explain the necessary tensors of Riemannian Geometry, then finally derive EFE, then dive into black holes and cosmology. The book will contain countess graphs and discrete 2D and 1 + 1d examples and EinsteinPy codes (I am a CS grad) to make it as visual as possible - while not sacrificing the necessary maths. TBH, part 1 and 2 of this are already published in Bangla, right now I am rewriting it in English for an international publication.
I need help about the publication process, steps of it.

What specifically is your question? "I need help" is not something specific enough for any of us to answer.

Go to your preferred publisher's webpage and submit a publication proposal.
Example for Springer. For this publisher you can also contact one of their Publishing Editors (here's the page for the ones in physics). Springer also has a guide for what to put in the publication proposal. You'll need to think carefully about the scope of your book, its length, its intended market, etc.
